# Exclude negative number from function to get and set margin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that I want to somewhat vertically center in the page. I want to get the viewport height and subtract from it the header, footer and main height. The resulting number will be divided by 3 and applied to the  element's margin-top. This works fine except when the window is shrunk vertically a negative number is being applied.

```
function getMargin() {
        var wHeight = $(window).height();
        var hHeight = $('header').height();
        var mHeight = $('main').height();
        var fHeight = $('footer').height();
        var height_diff = (wHeight - hHeight - mHeight - fHeight) / 3 + "px";
        //here is where its not working
        if ($(height_diff) >= '30px') {
            $('#content').css('margin-top', height_diff);
        } else {
            $('#content').css('margin-top', '40px');
        };
        console.log(height_diff);
    }
    $(window).resize(function(){
        getMargin();
    });
```

As long as the returned number (height_diff) is GREATER than 30px, apply it as margin, if it is less than 30px use the default. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would this ever work out to a logical expression?

```
 if ($(height_diff) >= '30px')
```

it wont.  Left side is a jquery element storing a number, right hand is a string with number and text.

lets fix the obvious and see where that leaves us

```
function getMargin() {
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    var hHeight = $('header').height();
    var mHeight = $('main').height();
    var fHeight = $('footer').height();
    var height_diff = (wHeight - hHeight - mHeight - fHeight) / 3;
    //here is where its not working
    if (height_diff >= 30) {
        $('#content').css('margin-top', height_diff + "px");
    } else {
        $('#content').css('margin-top', '40px');
    };
    console.log(height_diff);
}
$(window).resize(function(){
    getMargin();
});
```

something that would work even better from my perspective

```
    var height_diff = Math.max(30,(wHeight - hHeight - mHeight - fHeight) / 3);
     $('#content').css('margin-top', height_diff + "px");
```

no if else logic needed, but it means you either use the height_diff num or 30 if height_diff is less than 30 the result would be 30 not 40.

Comment: The additon at the end is very concise and much better than what I had envisioned. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're doing a mathematical comparison on a string. `>= '30px'` makes no logical sense.

Change

```
var height_diff = (wHeight - hHeight - mHeight - fHeight) / 3 + "px";
```

to

```
var height_diff = (wHeight - hHeight - mHeight - fHeight) / 3;
```

and change

```
if ($(height_diff) >= '30px') {
```

to

```
if ($(height_diff) >= 30) {
```

You can then add the "px" later (though you actually don't have to; jQuery's `.css()` infers pixels if a unit suffix is omitted.

Comment: The "height_diff" is a number so we don't need to do this "$(height_diff)" just this "height_diff". The "$(height_diff)" will return an array with the value of the "height_diff" valriable. Eg: "[40]"

Comment: Thank you, I apprecaite it. Good answer